# Arduino IDE - Ubuntu Mono Font Name?

Tags: arduino-ide

I know that you go to *preferences.txt* and there is `editor.font=` line setting, but I can't get what font name to type in there to use **Ubuntu Mono**. I would like to use that font please. I've tried:

```
Ubuntu_Mono
Ubuntu-Mono
Ubuntu Mono
Ubuntu+Mono
Ubuntu.Mono
UbuntuMono
Ubuntumono
ubuntumono
'Ubuntu Mono'
"Ubuntu Mono"
'UbuntuMono'
"UbuntuMono"
'Ubuntu-Mono'
"Ubuntu-Mono"
'Ubuntu_Mono'
"Ubuntu_Mono"
```

Thanks for answer :]

PS: Yes, I've restarted the studio every time, but some non-monotype/default font showed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the font, style and size.  I think you want

```
editor.font=Ubuntu Mono,plain,12
```

I don't know the exact name you should use for the font but you must have all three fields separated by commas.

The second field can be "plain", "bold" or "italic".

The third field is the font size, I'm not sure the units.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I googled that out yesterday and I'm just looking for the name.

Comment: Here are instructions for finding the font names available in java your platform: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/swing-faq-list-fonts-current-platform